# How to click the list item in web IE application with VBA

Tags: html, vba

Basically my requirement is to download the excel file from webpage through vba. I have written the code to login but unable to click on the list item. I need to iterate the loop through class and then list and tag a. So help me how can iterate through multiple option with vba.

I have attached the HTML source code i need to access hourly report from first list under Ul tag.

```
Sub DownloadIntraDayReport()`

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer 

ie.navigate "weblink" 

ie.Visible = True 

While ie.Busy DoEvents Wend 

Do Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE 

Set HTMLDoc = ie.document 

ie.document.getElementById("_58_login").Value = "username" 

ie.document.getElementById("_58_password").Value = "password" 

'ie.document.form().submit 

For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input") If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click 

Next 

End Sub
```

[Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhgCZ.png)

Image of page and HTML

[image: html]

Comment: It would help if you showed more HTML and your code so far. I have given the general syntax for selecting by ID, if scraping with IE, below.

Comment: Please [edit] you code into the question. Then highlight all the code and press Ctrl + K to format between code tags.

Comment: I have put your code in between code tags but please review my comment about checking your layout as the above won't compile. I gave a suggested pastebin link for what it might look like. https://pastebin.com/DJ4QMV37

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
IE.document.getElementById("scheduledReportList").Click
```

Where IE is the instance of Internet Explorer being used to scrape the page.